# Facebook og:image meta tag with one image displays multiple thumbnail previews

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook displays three thumbnail images when setting just one image in the Facebook og meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Keystone Business Products - Allentown, Reading, Scranton Copiers"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.keystonebp.com/img/quote.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.keystonebp.com/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Are you looking for a copier in the Allentown, Bethlehem, Scranton, or Reading areas? Read more about the family owned local dealership you can trust."/>
```

The first thumbnail image is the one I have set as the og:image.  The other two thumbnail images are images displayed in the body of the page.

The og image is 256x256 pixels.  My website is using PHP5.  The og:title, url, type, and description tags are all being displayed correctly.  The facebook debugger shows no warnings.

I'm not sure what else to say... I'm using a boilerplate template, the bizstrap corporate template.  The images being pulled are from a slider in the middle of the page.  Feel free to take a look at my website:

[keystonebp.com](http://www.keystonebp.com/)

I've found this question two other times on the board but neither one has an answer...

Comment: Hi Louis! I have the same problem. Have you found soluton?

Comment: You _have_ no `og:image` tag on that page . the debug tool shows that, and calling your script in the browser and viewing source code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that facebook cached the meta data of the URL. If you paste the same URL in the debug tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), that will invalidate the cache and facebook gets the correct thumbnails.